# How to trigger Button Click when everything is ready in google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map set up with geojson layer loaded with it. The geojson includes many polygon features.

I wanted to trigger those features click from specific button in the page and i've sucessfully done that by refering to this thread: [Google Maps - Trigger a click event on a data layer at a specific point (long/lat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317081/google-maps-trigger-a-click-event-on-a-data-layer-at-a-specific-point-long-la)

Now, what I want to do is whenever I open the page, the page will trigger specific button click. Or let say, whenever the document ready, trigger the button (that trigger feature click).

What things i did wrong so that i am unable to trigger the button click on ready function?

Here is what i've done:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#btnFirstLetter').click();
});

function initialize() {
  // Create a simple map.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -28, lng: 137.883}
  });
map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
  // Load a GeoJSON from the same server as our demo.
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(map.data,'addfeature',function(e){
      if(e.feature.getGeometry().getType()==='Polygon'){
          var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          
          e.feature.getGeometry().getArray().forEach(function(path){
          
             path.getArray().forEach(function(latLng){bounds.extend(latLng);})
          
          });
          e.feature.setProperty('bounds',bounds);
          
          new google.maps.Rectangle({map:map,bounds:bounds,clickable:false})
        
        }
  });
  
  $('#btnFirstLetter').click(function(){
   var firstLetter = 'G';
    
    map.data.forEach(function(feature){
     if (firstLetter == feature.getProperty('letter')){
       google.maps.event.trigger(map.data, 'click', {'feature': feature}); 
      }     
    });
  });
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(map.data,'click',function(e){
   var bounds=e.feature.getProperty('bounds');
    if(bounds){
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  })
  
  
  
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 90%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<button id="btnFirstLetter">
First Letter
</button>
```

Or this is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iam47/1Lxj2wf7/7/

Comment: the fiddle seems work rigfht for me  ..  what's the problem ??

Comment: Yes, there's no problem when we click the button. But, what i wanted to do is whenever the page loads, it will trigger the button click. That is the problem. @scaisEdge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The danger of setting a timeout is that you create a race condition which can lead to undesired results, particularly if you are calling data from an external source (slow network and geoJSON data takes 501 ms to arrive? bad luck...)

While `loadGeoJson` does provide a callback option for once the data has arrived, what you really want is to fire the click once the data has been rendered...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map.data,'addfeature',function(e){
  if(e.feature.getGeometry().getType()==='Polygon'){
      var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      e.feature.getGeometry().getArray().forEach(function(path){
         path.getArray().forEach(function(latLng){bounds.extend(latLng);})
      });
      e.feature.setProperty('bounds',bounds);
      new google.maps.Rectangle({map:map,bounds:bounds,clickable:false})
    }
    $('#btnFirstLetter').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do the different response to the  by different browser to the `DOMContentLoaded` event or `$(document).ready()` function  you could simply add  a sligth  timeout for wai the click invocation  ..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#btnFirstLetter').click();
  }, 500);

});
```

try reduce the timeout to your acceptable value